# Paste text in clipboard into a running exe

Tags: command-line, clipboard

Assume I have text in the file textFile.txt. Also assume I have a program *running* called aProgram.exe, which accepts pasted text.

What is the simplest way to create a script or batch that will capture the text in textFile.txt, open aProgram.exe and paste the contents of my clipboard?

Organised differently, how may I

1. Place text in textFile.txt into clipoard
2. Open aProgram.exe (which is already running)
3. Paste my clipboard *on* aProgram.exe (Control + V, is what I mean here)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could probably script this with AutoHotkeys.

Comment: http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/ ArsClip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this hybrid bat with vbs to do this with you, just save as `file.cmd`:

```bat
<!-- ::
@echo off & type "C:\folder\path\your\textFile.txt"| clip 
"%windir%\system32\WScript.exe" "%~dpnx0?.wsf" && goto :EOF || rem :: -->
<job><script language="vbscript">Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run ("""C:\\Program Files\\aProgram.exe"""),9
WScript.Sleep 3000: WshShell.SendKeys "^+v": </script></job>
```

The code above opens your program, edit this path below and according to the location of the program using **`\\`** instead **`\`**:

```bat
C:\\Program Files\\aProgram.exe
```

You also need to edit the path to your `textFile.txt`:

```bat
@echo off & type "C:\folder\path\your\textFile.txt" | clip
```

You may need to adjust the timeout on:

```bat
WScript.Sleep 3000
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Hybrid VBS/Bat Files](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html)**

  [√] **[WSF - Windows Script File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File)**

  [√] **[SendKeys Method in VBScript](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**

  [√] **[Execute Hybrid Bat/Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)**

---

For do the same in PowerShell

```bat
Get-Content -path "C:\folder\path\your\textFile.txt" | Set-Clipboard
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\\Program Files\\aProgram.exe'
Start-Sleep -m 700
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.AppActivate('add here the aProgram.exe windows name')
Start-Sleep -m 700 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{v}")
```

You also need to edit the path to your `textFile.txt`:

```bat
Get-Content -path "C:\folder\path\your\textFile.txt"  | Set-Clipboard
```

You may need to adjust the timeout on:

```bat
Start-Sleep -m 700
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**

  [√] **[start-process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)**

  [√] **[Start-Sleep](https://ss64.com/ps/start-sleep.html)**

  [√] **[Get-Clipboard](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html)**

  [√] **[SendKeys Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. What a fantastic and thoughtful response!

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo Is good to know that code works for you too, thkx! Sorry my limited /EN!